# If $x^{x^x} = 2^{-\sqrt{2}}$, find $x^{-2}$

Tags: exponentiation

I've been struggling with this one today. Applying the logarithmic function to both sides of the equation doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: prove that the LHS is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}^+$, then look for an "easy" solution.

Comment: As above, hint: $x=1/2$ (square root)

Comment: I was actually looking for a more analytical solution. The numerical one itself isn't hard to find by inspection, but analytically it seems to be tricky.

Comment: @RodrigoAlmeida The equation has no closed form solution in general (though monotonicity ensures that a solution exists and is unique). The choice of the RHS in this case makes it pretty obvious that the problem was about spotting the "easy" solution by inspection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of $\enspace\displaystyle 2^\frac{1}{2}=(2^2)^\frac{1}{2^2}\enspace$ you can write

$$x^x\ln x = -\sqrt{2}\ln 2 = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\ln 2 = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\ln \frac{1}{2^2} = \left(\frac{1}{2^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2^2}}\ln \frac{1}{2^2}$$

so that you get $\enspace\displaystyle x=\frac{1}{2^2}=0.25\enspace$ and therefore $\enspace\displaystyle x^{-2}=16$ .